# Why the readchar() return a byte, when it have to be a string

Tags: python

I have read the documentation about readchar, and there it says that the readchar method have to return a string, but when I run it returns bytes. I would like to understand why this happen, because I am new in the programming

a) This is the code I use to prove, and here say the data returned is a byte

```
     x = readchar.readchar()
     print(a)
     print(type(x))
```

b) This is the output in my consola

```
    b'a'
    <class 'bytes'>
```

c) This is the readchar documentation https://pypi.org/project/readchar/ or https://github.com/magmax/python-readchar

d) This is what says in the doc about it

> readchar()
> Reads the next char from stdin, returning it as a string with length 1.

PS. I made the same prove for readkey(), and this return a string according to the doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of this is history.  But to ease some of your concerns, "byte strings" and "strings" in Python 3 are very closely related.  The big difference is that "strings" are a sequence of Unicode code points, which are 16-bits (or 32-bits) wide, whereas "byte strings" are a sequence of 8-bit bytes.  If one is only using ASCII, you can store the same things in each (`"abcde"` vs `b"abcde"`).  You can convert between the two by using `bytes.decode()` and `str.encode()`, assuming you know the character set you want.

Byte strings make more sense if you're going to get things that are not really characters in a specific language.  That's the case when reading raw keystrokes from a keyboard device, as is the case here.  `readkey` interprets the raw keystroke bytes and converts it to a Unicode string.  `readchar` is lower level than that.

This package started out in Python 2.  There, the native strings were byte strings, and you had to take special steps to make Unicode strings.  That's probably where the difference originated.

Answer (score 0):

It returns it, as a "byte chain" (which is the bytes of the UTF-8 chain, not displayed as characters, but as a "byte chain").

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Python types: bytes, bytearray

A Python string is a sequence (list) of characters. If we stick to ASCII each character can be represented by an 8 bit number.

But we don't stick to ASCII. Unicode gives us öäü€ß¹ etc

A Python string containing Unicode characters can need more than 1 byte per character.

Raw devices like files, serial ports etc return a bytes object describing all the Unicode characters as bytes.

Now a Unicode byte buffer can be converted to a string by:

```
mystring = mybytes.decode('utf-8')
```

which can raise an Exception if the it's not a valid utf-8 encoding.

Why all this complication?

Because files and devices are inherently byte devices, and strings which seem simple to humans are complex beasts for the Python engine.